# Flutter Web: Automatic translation of the website from the browser

Tags: flutter, browser, translation

I would like to enable visitors to my flutter website to translate the language of my website using the Brwoser internal translation function. Unfortunately, this does not work when I create a new flutter web project.

In Safari, a small translation icon is displayed in the search bar on the right-hand side of every website I visit, but not on a newly created default Flutter website.

In Chrome, there is the option to select text and translate it, but when I click on the "Translate entire page" button, nothing happens.

This can easily be reproduced by creating a new flutter web project.

It would be great if someone could tell me what I need to do to make this function work on my website. Thank you very much!